# Ubuntu software center opening issue on 16.04 LTS

Tags: software-center

I got problem when opening Ubuntu software center. When I click on it, it pop out and go within like 2 sec. Please help me with this issue because I want to install Whatsapp web-app.

When I try to download it using terminal instead of Ubuntu Software center due to above issue I got following error massage.

```
**dpkg: error processing archive whatsapp-webapp_1.0_all.deb (--install):
cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
whatsapp-webapp_1.0_all.deb**
```

Is it due to above software center issue or is it for anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
wget -P Downloads/ https://www.thefanclub.co.za/sites/default/files/public/downloads/whatsapp-webapp_1.0_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/whatsapp-webapp_1.0_all.deb
```

The problem `cannot access archieve: No such file or directory` indicate that the `.deb` file may not exist on your working directory, above command will download `whatsapp-webapp_1.0_all.deb` to `~/Downloads`, then we'll use `dpkg` for install `whatsapp-webapp_1.0_all.deb`.

Comment: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!